# Finding the similarity transformation between two symbol matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, findinstance

I have two symbol matrices `mA` and `mB`, which are similar matrices.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
perm = RandomSample[Range[6]];
MatrixForm[mP = IdentityMatrix[6][[perm]]];
```

> mP=$\left(\begin{array}{llllll}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$

```
MatrixForm[mA = Array[a, {6, 6}]]
MatrixForm[mB = Inverse[mP].mA.mP]
```

> mA=$\left(\begin{array}{llllll}a[1,1] & a[1,2] & a[1,3] & a[1,4] & a[1,5] & a[1,6] \\ a[2,1] & a[2,2] & a[2,3] & a[2,4] & a[2,5] & a[2,6] \\ a[3,1] & a[3,2] & a[3,3] & a[3,4] & a[3,5] & a[3,6] \\ a[4,1] & a[4,2] & a[4,3] & a[4,4] & a[4,5] & a[4,6] \\ a[5,1] & a[5,2] & a[5,3] & a[5,4] & a[5,5] & a[5,6] \\ a[6,1] & a[6,2] & a[6,3] & a[6,4] & a[6,5] & a[6,6]\end{array}\right)$

> mB=$\left(\begin{array}{llllll}a[5,5] & a[5,4] & a[5,6] & a[5,3] & a[5,2] & a[5,1] \\ a[4,5] & a[4,4] & a[4,6] & a[4,3] & a[4,2] & a[4,1] \\ a[6,5] & a[6,4] & a[6,6] & a[6,3] & a[6,2] & a[6,1] \\ a[3,5] & a[3,4] & a[3,6] & a[3,3] & a[3,2] & a[3,1] \\ a[2,5] & a[2,4] & a[2,6] & a[2,3] & a[2,2] & a[2,1] \\ a[1,5] & a[1,4] & a[1,6] & a[1,3] & a[1,2] & a[1,1]\end{array}\right)$

However, if the symbol matrices mA and mB are known, it is difficult to get `mP` in `mB=Inverse [mP]. mA.mP`. The following code can only get the zero matrix:

```
MatrixForm[mQ = Array[q, {6, 6}]];
listmQ = Flatten[mQ];
sol = FindInstance[mQ.mB == mA.mQ, listmQ]
```

> $\begin{aligned} & \{\{q[1,1] \rightarrow 0\,... , q[6,6] \rightarrow 0\}\} \\ & \end{aligned}$

The correct result should be

> mQ=$\left(\begin{array}{llllll}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$

How to get this result?

There are some similar questions, but there is no related topic about the similar transformation of symbol matrix.

[Finding the similarity transformation between two matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226664/finding-the-similarity-transformation-between-two-matrices)

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2532981

https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix2.html#sage.matrix.matrix2.Matrix.is_similar

**EDIT**
The general solution of the 3x3 matrix can be obtained by using the following code, but for the 6x6 matrix in my question, the code has been running and unable to return the results.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226666/69835

```
Clear["Global`*"];
perm = RandomSample[Range[3]];
MatrixForm[mP = IdentityMatrix[3][[perm]]]
MatrixForm[mA = Array[a, {3, 3}]]
MatrixForm[mB = Inverse[mP] . mA . mP]
n = Length@mA;
Id = IdentityMatrix@n;
solxy = SolveAlways[Det[mA - l*Id] == Det[mB - l*Id], l];
mA = mA /. solxy[[1]];
mB = mB /. solxy[[1]];
mP = Array[p, {n, n}];
solP = Solve[mP . mB == mA . mP, Flatten@mP];
mP = mP /. solP[[1]]


mB == Inverse@mP . mA . mP // Simplify
```

> True

***Is there a better way to solve the 6x6 matrix in my question?***